# Link to open VF page beside a field

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-link, detail-page, actionlink

I have a requirement to place a link beside a custom field value in a detail page. Can someone tell me how that can be feasible? I am not getting such a thing in net surfing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i am doing is field name:'Click Here to parse data' and the field is of formula type : then added below :

```
HYPERLINK( "/apex/multiplejsondata" ,
   IMAGE("resource/1436865013000/rekhanallam__jsonparser", "No static Resource")
 )
```

I just loaded this image in static resource and using as when users see it , they can see as a button so, and my client loves it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a formula (text) field that will show the custom field value and in addition a hyperlink to the page. Then just swap the fields on the layout and display the formula field instead of the original custom field (unless it need to be visible for inline editing).

Your formula should look like this:

```
Custom_Field__c + " " + HYPERLINK("/apex/YourVFPage", "Link Name", "_blank")
```

Comment: I am already having this hyperlink in detail page. How can I incorporate it here? IF(ISBLANK(Call_abv__r.Parent_Call_vod__c), IF( Call_Load_abv__c , HYPERLINK("/" + Call_abv__c, Call_abv__r.Name), (Call_abv__r.Name) ) , IF( Call_Load_abv__c ,
HYPERLINK("/" + Call_abv__r.Parent_Call_vod__c,Call_abv__r.Parent_Call_vod__r.Name),(Call_abv__r.Name)))